# Sending a room-bound event via ews

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I send an event using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-create-appointments-and-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange-2013

The event is created, only for participants. No event is generated in the room. How do I send an event to a room?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
      <t:TimeZoneContext>
         <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Pacific Standard Time" />
      </t:TimeZoneContext>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <m:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
         <m:Items>
            <t:CalendarItem>
               <t:Subject>Team building exercise</t:Subject>
               <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Let's learn to really work as a team and then have lunch!</t:Body>
               <t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>60</t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
               <t:Start>2013-09-21T16:00:00.000Z</t:Start>
               <t:End>2013-09-21T20:00:00.000Z</t:End>
               <t:Location>Conference Room 12</t:Location>
               <t:RequiredAttendees>
                  <t:Attendee>
                     <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>Mack.Chaves@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                     </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Attendee>
                  <t:Attendee>
                     <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>Sadie.Daniels@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                     </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Attendee>
               </t:RequiredAttendees>
               <t:OptionalAttendees>
                  <t:Attendee>
                     <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>Magdalena.Kemp@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                     </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Attendee>
               </t:OptionalAttendees>
               <t:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="Pacific Standard Time" />
            </t:CalendarItem>
         </m:Items>
      </m:CreateItem>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the resource element https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/resources and include your Room as an attendee
eg

```html
</t:OptionalAttendees>
<t:Resources>
  <t:Attendee>
    <t:Mailbox>
      <t:Name>Resource1</t:Name>
      <t:EmailAddress>resource1@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
      <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
      <t:MailboxType>Mailbox</t:MailboxType>
    </t:Mailbox>
    <t:ResponseType>Unknown</t:ResponseType>
  </t:Attendee>
</t:Resources>
</t:CalendarItem>
```

Comment: Do you need to specify both the participants and the room?

Comment: The room is an attendee of the Meeting specified under the resource node if you creating a meeting with attendees and you want invitations sent to everyone then yes.

Comment: How do you know if a room is approved or not?

Comment: You don't you need to wait for the invitation to be sent the Calendar assistant to process the invitation and apply whatever booking polices are in place and it will then respond that it has accepted or rejected the request